# visual studio community template location

Tags: macos, botframework

I thought I'd have a play around with the BotBuilder tools for Visual Studio. Have downloaded the BotBuilder Template but as I'm using Visual Studio Community for Mac I've no idea where this template should go and can't find it anywhere in the docs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you have a look to `~/Library/Application Support/VisualStudio/x.x/LocalInstall/Addins` (x.x is a version number)

Comment: Hi Nicholas, thanks for the reply. I go to Library/Application Support but I do not have a VisualStudio folder. I should add it's Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

BotBuilder was not built with the intention to be compatible with Mono. This is not necessarily impossible, but it is not something currently officially supported. To build C# bots with the V3 SDK it would be easiest to do so on a windows machine, partition, or VM. For the V3 SDK Node.js is intended as to be the multi-platform solution.

For reference with regard to the template location, the path is ~/Library/VisualStudio/x.x/LocalInstall/Addins